# Unix Bash Array not displaying all elements

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Here is my array set in Unix Bash. 
I am unable to read array using [0] or [1]

```
$ array=(yeah go)
$ echo $array
yeah
$ echo $array[0]
yeah[0]
$
```

Help me.

Comment: Should be: `echo "${array[@]}"` and `echo "${array[0]}"`

Comment: @anubhava - looks like you should make that an answer

Comment: Thanks @BrianAgnew: Converted it into an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To print all elements of an array use:

```
echo "${arr[@]}"
```

OR

```
printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}"
```

To print an individual element by index use;

```
echo "${arr[0]}"
```

OR

```
echo "${arr[1]}"
```

[Read more about BASH arrays](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays)

Comment: Thanks for the answer:)
could you please help with this question as well ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21757669/syntax-error-issue-while-storing-array-value-unix-solaris-korn-shell

Comment: I'd suggest the BashGuide as a better reference than the ABS -- over in freenode's #bash, we're having to help people unlearn bad habits they got from the ABS much too often.

Comment: ...the guide page on arrays is http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : I have the same problem now. can you please here for the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21757669/syntax-error-issue-while-storing-array-value-unix-solaris-korn-shell

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Good point about link, I updated it.