# syntax error issue while storing array value Unix Solaris Korn Shell

Tags: linux, shell, unix, solaris, ksh

Here is my command in shell script.

```
x=($(echo $x1 | cut -f3 -d" " | cut -f1 -d"]"))
```

> syntax error at line 818 : `(' unexpected

**If I remove this line its working**

Note: The same script runs in Linux OS when i try it in Solaris it throws error.

Comment: It may be due to the version of the shell, what does `bash --version` show on your Linux vs Solaris machines?

Comment: GNU bash, version 3.00.16(1)-release (sparc-sun-solaris2.10)

Comment: Also, is the script actually running under bash, or under "plain" sh? That looks a lot like an error from a shell that doesn't support arrays.

Comment: i run it using ksh script.sh

Comment: In that case, it's running under the Korn shell (`ksh`), not bash; you should adjust the title and tags appropriately.

Comment: @GordonDavisson : Could you please help me what to change ?

Comment: @GordonDavisson : I have asked help for solution too ?

Comment: I've edited the question; it might also be good to add the ksh version (find it with `ksh -c 'echo $KSH_VERSION'`). Unfortunately, I'm not very familiar ksh, and I don't recognize the cause of this problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47435/discussion-between-logan-and-gordon-davisson)

Comment: @logan: Make sure you're using BASH while using arrays.

Comment: @anubhava : which means ? should i call i the script as bash script.sh ?

Comment: Yes absolutely correct and `script.sh` should have `#!/bin/bash` as first line.

Comment: @logan: The name of the script doesn't matter; what matters is the `#!/bin/bash` on the first line. You don't need any particular suffix at all. Be sure to `chmod +x` the script file, and run the script directly rather than feeding it to a shell: just `./foo`, not `bash ./foo` or `sh ./foo` or `ksh ./foo`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your ksh version:

ksh93

```
$ ksh --version
  version         sh (AT&T Research) 93u+ 2012-08-01

$ x1="one two three]four"
$ x=($(echo $x1 | cut -f3 -d" " | cut -f1 -d"]"))
$ echo ${x[0]}
three
```

ksh88

```
$ what /usr/bin/ksh
/usr/bin/ksh:
        Version M-11/16/88i
        SunOS 5.8 Generic 110662-24 Apr 2007

$ x1="one two three]four"
$ x=($(echo $x1 | cut -f3 -d" " | cut -f1 -d"]"))
ksh: syntax error: `(' unexpected
```

Comment: To add to this: ksh88 doesn't support the `var=(...)` syntax for arrays. It uses `set -A var val1 val2 ...`.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick, very good point. And that is valid ksh93 as well

Comment: @glennjackman : you did not tell me how solve the problem in ksh88 ?

Comment: ksh88 does not have arrays. you're just extracting a single word, so what do you need an array for? `x=$(echo $x1 | cut -f3 -d" " | cut -f1 -d"]")`

Answer (score 0):

execute below one it will work..using ksh..

```
x1="test1 test2 test3]testarray test"
x="$(echo $x1 | cut -f3 -d" " | cut -f1 -d"]")"
echo $x
```

Comment: output is going to be "test3"